# Aspose.Word - How to make use of full table cell width?

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I have a table in a word document and would like to make use of FULL cell width to insert data.

Default behaviour is that it is leaving spaces (padding) as below.
[image]

How can i make use of the total width of a column without leaving any space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aspose.Words to adjust amount of space (in points) to the left, right, below or above the contents of cells. Please try using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"input.docx");

Table tab = doc.FirstSection.Body.Tables[0];

tab.BottomPadding = 0;
tab.LeftPadding = 0;
tab.RightPadding = 0;
tab.TopPadding = 0;

doc.Save(MyDir + @"17.7.docx");
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: How to set left and right paddings to 0 and leave default values for top and bottom paddings

Comment: In this case you should only specify Table.LeftPadding = 0; and Table.RightPadding = 0; And there is no need to use Table.BottomPadding and Table.TopPadding properties. Hope, this helps.